# Spin conservation in indirect optical transitions in bilayer TMDC

Tags: conservation-laws, quantum-spin, semiconductor-physics, quantum-optics

While I was reading this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09129), I got confused with the spin conservation in optical transitions in bilayer 2D semiconductors. In figure 3(d), indirect transition between K and Q valleys are shown and it seems like the optical transitions between K and Q valleys with opposite spins are allowed (for example, transition between K (spin up) and Q(spin down) valleys).

I know that the spin should be conserved in a direct optical transition in monolayer TMDCs so transition between the bands with opposite spins are spin dark excitons, but I don't understand how an indirect optical transition in a bilayer system gets away with the spin conservation. Is dipole transition selection rule not valid here? Could somebody explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Spin will be conserved in an indirect transition if the third particle is spinless. That is, phonons in most cases have spin 0, so a phonon-mediated indirect transition will conserve spin just as a direct transition does.